# Time Series Anomaly Detection with Class Variables

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, anomaly-detection, artificial-intelligence, isolation-forest

In ("univariate") time series anomaly detection, what techniques are there to incorporate class variables?

For example, in accounting transactional data, we might care about anomalies in the variable "transaction amount". However, we also have many class variables ("account id", "country", "number of transactions in this month") at our disposal.

There are anomaly detection algorithms for finding anomalies in a univariate time series (e.g. autoregressive forecasts with probability bands), but they do not take into account the class variables.

There are also anomaly detection algorithms for finding anomalies in multivariate data (e.g. isolation forests), but they will also filter for anomalies in the other class variable combinations, which we care less about.

Are there anomaly detection algorithms for finding anomalies in time series data, taking into account class variables?